# Lock control for editing in Powerpoint using Office-JS

Tags: office-js, powerpoint-addins

I've read the documentation that Microsoft has about Powerpoint addins: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint), but I can't find a solution for the following usecase:

**I need a content control that has the possibility to insert images, text and set tags to it as well as the possibility to block the user from editing the control.**

Do you know which control can be used for this usecase or if the powerpoint supports this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerPoint doesn't have content controls. Only Word does. In PowerPoint, images, and text blocks are "shapes". You can programmatically add shapes to the presentation and programmatically tag them by using the Shapes and Tags APIs in the PowerPoint-specific object model.

Comment: Thanks for responding, so that means that the shapes does not provide a way to "lock" the content inside of them? I haven't seen something helping for this use case in their Shape or Shape Collections APIs

Comment: No there's no way to lock them.